# Magento 2: New Customers display issue in Admin Customer Grid

Tags: magento2, customer-grid

In Magento 2.1.8, Customer Grid is populating from table `customer_grid_flat` rather than `customer_entity`. This is for fastest retrieval of data. But the problem is `customer_grid_flat` never gets populate until I manually reindex the grid using SSH.

For a quick hack I have changed the code in blow file

Line 37: vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/Grid

Old Code

```
$mainTable = 'customer_grid_flat',
```

New Code

```
$mainTable = 'customer_entity', //'customer_grid_flat',
```

Now some columns are not showing data like Name, Phone, Country etc. because of missing joins with relevant tables. Can anyone please suggest any better solution.

Comment: run this command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid`  after check it
check your indexer settings and crontab setup!

Comment: @RakeshDonga I mentioned that I can manually reindex the grid using command you mentioned. But I want automated process. Crons are working. Index status is 'valid' always. Crontab setup is correct.

Comment: @ZulqarnainAbdulJabbar have you tried `Update on Save` mode in admin for the cutomer grid?

Comment: you have raised a good point. +1 for that

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Go to

> System -> Index Management

Check if customer data cron is set to **"Update on Save"**, if it is not, then set it.

[image]

**Step 2:** check if cron scheduled properly, if it is not then set it through shell.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/Your_Project/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/Your_Project/var/log/magent$
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/Your_Project/update/cron.php >> /var/www/Your_Project/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /var/www/Your_Project/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/Your_Project/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

**Note: You need to set location of your project and php path propely in scheduling**

**Step 3:** Go to:

> Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System

Expend tab: **Cron (Scheduled Task)**

Make sure **"General Scheduled Every"** is set to **1**

Comment: Thank you @Shoaib for your valuable response. 'Update on Save' is not working for me. At least 22 new customers from Yesterday till now but not reflecting in the grid until I reindex the grid via reindex command. Cron setup is correct at my end. If I set customer-grid reindex to 'invalid' then cron picks it and updates the grid. Problem is, reindexer is not setting to 'invalid' after new customer creation in the system. I am thinking to do this [link](https://www.activo.com/how-to-change-index-status-to-reindex-required) now to invalidate the index after new signup. Link is of Magento 1

Comment: check table `cron_schedule` it will tell you the error if something happening wrong. I had faced same issue before, and got error from this table

Comment: there is no error in cron. But let me tell you that 'Update on Save' is now working. I have to run the reindex command one time manually and now customer grid is getting update on each customer save. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ZulqarnainAbdulJabbar, I am also facing same issue. I have checked with both options "Update on Schedule" and "Update on Save". Both options are not working for me. In my case, I am creating customer programmatically which are not showing in customer grid in admin without running indexing command manually. Any idea what can be done?

Comment: @PratikNavapara probably your magento cronjob is not scheduled. Schedule it using this command on shell. `php bin/magento cron:install`

Comment: @PratikNavapara you need to make sure that cron jobs are working. You need to follow all of the steps mentioned in Answer 1.

Comment: @ZulqarnainAbdulJabbar, all crons are working fine. Still I am getting this issue. If I create customer from registration page then it is sync in customer grid instantly. But when I create it programmatically it is not synchronising in customer grid table. Any idea what to do?

Comment: If from normal create account it is showing on grid, then your create account code would have some issue, please ask this question separately and paste link here. I have create account working code, I will help you out on this

Answer (score -1):

It is the issue of indexing.

Go to the System -> Index Management. If the customer gird status is not ready then follow the below steps.

execute the following command for reindexing the customer grid.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

Then after clear and flush the cache using the following command

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```